# Unsupported/Invalid URL(s) when trying to add source to Language Studio knowledge base

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, nlp-question-answering, language-studio

I am trying to add a source from a Sharepoint page or Word document stored in Sharepoint using the URL-option I get the following error message: Unsupported/Invalid URL(s). It works just fine when adding a URL like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/support/qna-faq. It also works fine when I download the Word document locally and then upload it to Language Studio using the Files-option. Does anyone know what the problem might be? Can it be an access problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a sharepoint url from intranet to qnamaker as given below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources

In language studio as a workaround, copy the question and Answer content and save it in .docx, pdf,.tsv or any other supported file format, and upload the same for creating knowledgebase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, we came across that solution but that would require the QnAMakerPortalSharepoint app to have these permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources#active-directory-manager-grant-file-read-access-to-qna-maker. Ideally, we wouldn't want the app to, for example, be able to read items in all site locations just because we want to import a simple Word document to Language Studio.

Download/upload the document is also a solution, but since we will continuously update the QnA:s, it is not viable for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, Language Studio doesn't support this now, will be supporting in the near future.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can you be more specific about the near future? Is it weeks or months?

Comment: Added to the backlog, I will check with the team and let you know the timeframe.